# How do I find out the "redo log file max size" in Oracle 11R2

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I'm working with Oracle 11R2 and I want to see the max size of my redo log files (I didn't install Oracle so I'm not aware of the configuration).

I have searched the Internet but all I have found concerns the way to erase and replace it.

Is there anywhere in the data dictionary I can find this information?

I’ve already tried  `v$log` and `v$parameter` but I haven't found what I'm looking for.

Comment: You we're close enough with v$log -> v$logfile :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/onlineredo.htm#i1006398 i think from v$logfile, i don't know if it is correct....let me know

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the size of the redo log members (files on disk) size, then use the query below:

```
-- Show Redo Logs info
set linesize 300
column REDOLOG_FILE_NAME format a50
SELECT
    a.GROUP#,
    a.THREAD#,
    a.SEQUENCE#,
    a.ARCHIVED,
    a.STATUS,
    b.MEMBER    AS REDOLOG_FILE_NAME,
    (a.BYTES/1024/1024) AS SIZE_MB
FROM v$log a
JOIN v$logfile b ON a.Group#=b.Group# 
ORDER BY a.GROUP# ASC;
```

The query output should look like:

```
GROUP   #THREAD#  SEQUENCE# ARC STATUS   REDOLOG_FILE_NAME      SIZE_MB 
---------- ---------- ---------- --- ---------------- ---------------------
1       1       4 YES INACTIVE /ORACLE/oradata/orcl1/redo01.log   50 
2       1       5 YES INACTIVE /ORACLE/oradata/orcl1/redo02.log   50 
3       1       6 NO  CURRENT  /ORACLE/oradata/orcl1/redo03.log   50
```

Comment: Isn't the query missing a join condition between v$log and v$logfile?

Comment: Added a join on Group#.